# Escape when echoed

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, security, escaping

I've been trying to submit a plugin for review and I keep having problems with the echo line.
The last version I sent was like this.

```
<option value="">
    <?php _e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    $folder = esc_attr( $folder );
    echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
} ?>
```

And the WordPress response was:

> This is not escaped:
>
> ```
> echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
> ```
>
> $folder MUST be escaped when it's echo'd.

Now I'm ready to submit the code for review again but first I want to make sure I'm correct.

Here the new code

```
<option value="">
    <?php _e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '">' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '</option>';
} ?>
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help, as I'm a bit confused about the (escaped).

Comment: They might not have flagged this as it isn't a security issue, but `_e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN );` is not valid. You cannot use variables (or constants or functions) in place of a text domain - you can _only_ use a string.

Comment: @vancoder - Oh... I didn't know that, thanks for noticing... although I haven't been told anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact to be super pedantic, I think the correct code is actually:

```
echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $folder ) . '">' . esc_html( $folder ) . '</option>';
```

Since the first variable is an attribute, and the second is encased in html, although I wold bet that the code you have would pass review, and is certainly fit for purpose.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for your answer.